# SQL Query Involving Finding Most Frequent Tuple Value in Column

Tags: sql, join

**I have the following relations:**

- teaches(ID,course_id,sec_id,semester,year)
- instructor(ID,name,dept_name,salary)

**I am trying to express the following as an SQL query:**

Find the ID and name of the instructor who has taught the most courses(i.e has the most tuples in teaches).

**My Query**

```
select ID, name 
from teaches 
  natural join instructor
group by ID
order by count(*) desc
```

**I know this isn't correct**, but I feel like I'm on the right track. In order to answer the question, you need to work with both relations, hence the natural join operation is required. Since the question asks for the instructor that has taught the **most** courses, that tells me that we are trying to count the number of times each instructor ID appears in the teaches relation. From what I understand, we are looking to count distinct instructor IDs, hence the group by command is needed.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes version & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. Show correct relevant parts you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use natural joins: all they do is rely on column names to decide which columns relate across tables (they don't check for foreign keys constraints or the-like, as you would thought). This is unreliable by nature.

You can use a regular `inner join`:

```
select i.id, i.name 
from teaches t
inner join instructor i on i.id = t.sec_id
group by i.id, i.name
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Notes:

- this assumes that column `teaches.sec_id` relates to `instructor.id` (I cannot see which other column could be used)
- I added a `limit` clause to the query since you stated that you want the top instructor - the syntax may vary across databases
- always prefix the column names with the table they belong to, to make the query unambiguous and easier to understand
- it is a good practice (and a requirement in many databases) that in an aggregate query all non-aggregared columns listed in the `select` clause should appear in the `group by` clause; I added the instructur name to your `group by` clause